# Excel: Count same number values in noncontiguous range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for the most elegant way to count the same number values in a noncontiguous range (I'll refer to it as just 'range'). This is the range:

```
=$C$2:$C$31,$E$2:$E$31,$G$2:$G$31,$I$2:$I$31,$K$2:$K$31,$M$2:$M$31,$O$2:$O$31,$Q$2:$Q$31,$S$2:$S$7
```

These are the parameters:

- The range contains non-adjacent columns.
- The columns differ in height.
- The cells in the range are either empty or contain integers.
- I'm checking for how many cells equal '1', how many equal '2' etc. in the range. (Not in one go, but in seperate formulas).
- I've used a named range to reference the range. I'd really like to use this named range in the formula, in one way or another.

I hope I've given you enough info... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use excel built in function Countif, but it won't work with non-contigous range. The other way (the easy way) will be to use VBA to create your own custom function, and then use it in excel.
I've presented that technique here.

Goto visual basic editor in excel by pressing Alt+F11, in the project window insert a new module and paste the below code:

```
Function countif_n(rng As Range, key As Range) As Integer

Dim count As Integer
count = 0

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = key.Value Then
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next cell

countif_n = count

End Function
```

Here rng is your non-contigous range, and key represent the "range"(cell) which contains the value you want to count. For eg., to check for 1 enter 1 in any cell lets suppose "F2", and your non-contigous range is "testrange"

Then use the above function by entering the following in any blank cell:

```
=countif_n(testrange, F2)
```

Comment: surely this is over complicating the situation

Comment: Thanks, I guess VBA is the answer then! :)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Kartik that a VBA solution is required.  However the solution offered is a little inefficient in that it loops over every cell in the ranged passed into the function.  It also limits the `key` parameter to a range reference, and can only count up to 32767 matches.  Here's an alternative addresses these shortcomings

```
Function CountIf_N(rng As Range, key As Variant) As Variant
    Dim r As Range
    Dim count As Long
    count = 0
    For Each r In rng.Areas
        count = count + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(r, key)
    Next
    CountIf_N = count
End Function
```

Note: assumes Excel 07 or later.  If using with an ealier version replace `CountIfs` with `CountIf`

Comment: How do you format the non-contiguous range when putting it into the function?

Answer (score 1):

Although COUNTIF can't handle non-contiguous ranges some functions can, for example RANK and COUNT so for a range called **Range** this formula will give the number of instances of a number in Z2 within **Range**

`=IFERROR(COUNT(Range)-SUM(RANK(Z2,Range,{1,0}))+2,0)`

assumes Excel 2007 or later but can be amended to work in earlier versions

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite work if there's stuff below S7 that can't be counted, but you may be able to modify.  It also doesn't incorporate the named range.

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN(A2:S31),2)=0,IF(A2:S31=2,1,0)))
```

This example counts the number of 2's.

This needs to be array-entered with `ctrl-shift-enter`.  It's based on the fact that you're counting in every other column, at least in your example.  Also, although you mention the columns are different heights, it looks like all except S are the same height.  So maybe there's a way to work around that.